# Hibernate Envers - How to search for string primary key?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am unable to find proper query for finding auditing records based on string as a primary key. However all other functionality is running fine with proper auditing of the given table.

Here is a code of my domain object:

```
private String userName;
private Date createDate;
private Date modifyDate;

@Id
@Column(name = "user_name", nullable = false, length = 10)
public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
```

And here is the code for query i am searching, here propertyValue is the name of user by which I want to search:

```
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery()  
      .forRevisionsOfEntity(targetClass, false, true)
      .add(AuditEntity.revisionType().ge(RevisionType.ADD))
      .add(AuditEntity.property("userName").eq(propertyValue))
      .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc()); 

    return query.getResultList();
```

I got `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property userName` exception by running this query.

Is there a different way of dealing with string primary keys ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no property named `username` the class does have an id. Change your code to use `AuditEntity.id()` instead of `AuditEntity.property(..)`.

```
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery()  
  .forRevisionsOfEntity(targetClass, false, true)
  .add(AuditEntity.revisionType().ge(RevisionType.ADD))
  .add(AuditEntity.property("userName").eq(propertyValue))
  .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc());
```

Use this instead

```
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery()  
  .forRevisionsOfEntity(targetClass, false, true)
  .add(AuditEntity.revisionType().ge(RevisionType.ADD))
  .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(propertyValue))
  .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc());
```

Comment: Thanks, now it is working. I used to think id is only applicable to integer id's.